# package textpos gives Runaway argument error

Tags: errors, pdftex, textpos

I am trying to position images in order to make a "stamp" pdf for use with pdftk.
textpos looks like the perfect solution, but this code gives errors and no output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[absolute,verbose]{textpos}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{210}{20,55} 
Pictures should have been here
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{EAmerke_sort.pdf}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{code.pdf}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

pdflate says: 
Runaway argument?
0]{20,55} Pictures should have been here \includegraphics [scale=0.5]\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \TP@textblock.
 
                \par

Answer (score 4):

The second argument should use picture mode coordinate syntax `()` not `{}`

```
\begin{textblock}{210}(20,55)
```

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCarlisle! Finally I have a pdf so I can tweak the coordinates.